# Una promesa me retorna el resultado intercambiado al ejecutarla. Me retorna el reject por el resolve y el resolve por el reject

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas

Tengo un problema en un proyecto en el que subo archivos a Cloudinary. Genero un documento (se llama Documento también la colección) en Mongo con información del archivo subido. Este Documento también se agrega  en un arreglo de otra entidad llamada Proceso y actualizo el Proceso:

Esta es la función que retorna la promesa:

```
const cargarArchivo = async (idProceso, file) => {
const proceso = await Proceso.findById(idProceso);
return new Promise(async(reject, resolve)=>{
    if(!proceso){
        reject(`No existe un proceso con el ID ${idProceso}`);
        return;
    }
    
    if(file){
        const {name} = file;
        const nombreCortado = file.name.split('.');
        const extension = nombreCortado[nombreCortado.length - 1];
        console.log(`Nombre: ${nombreCortado} Extensión: ${extension}`)
        if(extension!== 'pdf'){
           reject(`El archivo ${name} no tiene extensión pdf!`);
        }
        const {secure_url} = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(file.tempFilePath);
        console.log('Se subió a cloudinary');
        const dataDoc = {
            proceso: idProceso,
            nombre: name,
            path: secure_url
        }
        const doc = new Documento(dataDoc);
        console.log('Se creó el nuevo documento');
        //guardar en la referencia
        proceso.archivos.push(doc);
        console.log('Se insertó el nuevo documento en el proceso');
        await doc.save();
        console.log('Se actualizó el proceso');
        await proceso.save()
        resolve(`Se agregó un documento en el proceso con el código: ${proceso.codigo}`);
        return;
    }
    else{
    reject('No existe un archivo en la petición');
    return;
}
})
```

}

En esta función recibo el _id del proceso y el archivo. Entonces, extraigo el nombre, valido que el formato sea PDF, valido que el archivo llegue (file), lo subo a Cloudinary y aquí me retorna el link del archivo subido. Luego creo un Documento con el idProceso, nombre y el path. Creo un nuevo Documento con esta información y la añado al proceso.archivos con push, guardo el documento y actualizo Proceso.

EL PROBLEMA

Cuando invoco esta función en el controlador, me retorna el resolve, pero lo atrapa en el catch. Y si algo falla como el formato que no sea PDF, lo ejecuta en el try.

```
 try {
        const msg = await cargarArchivo(idProceso, files);
        return res.status(201).json({msg: msg});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error desde la promesa: ', error);
        return res.status(500).json({msg: error});
    }
```

Funciona todo bien pero se cruza el resultado de la promesa y no encuentro la falla de porque.
Así hago la petición desde Postman y me retorna, el resultado ejecutándose en el catch y retornando un status 500. Sin embargo todo la lógica de la promesa funciona bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si la hago fallar mandando un formato invalido, se ejecuta en el try y me retorna un status 201

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este error me produce en la consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ejecuta alreves y no encuentro la falla.

Comment: Te retorna bien, solo que estás pasando mal los nombres en el `callback` de tu Promesa. Tienes: `return new Promise(async(reject, resolve) => {...}`, però lo correcto es: `return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {...}`. Saludos

Comment: Si cierto. Que error tan tonto. Gracias amigo